# Insert method output not as expected i thought it corresponds to (index,value) what is the reason behind this

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, arraylist

why is the output as below

```
g=[] 
g.insert(3,5)
g.insert(2,6)
g.insert(1,7)
g.insert(0,8)

print(g)
```

was expecting `[8,7,6,5]`

but the O/P is `[8, 5, 7, 6]`

Comment: Yuo can't insert at a position in the list that doesn't exist. If the first argument to `insert()` is too high, the element is inserted at the end.

Comment: Try putting `print(g)` after each insertion to see what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

```
    g= []
    g.insert(3,8)
    print(g[0]) -> O/P - 8
    print(g[3]) -> O/P - It will give an error.
```

If the list is empty and you will try to insert at any other position except 0, it will store that value only at position 0.